# What functions do we need besides polynomials to describe any real as the root of some equation?

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

If $f(x)$ is some polynomial with integer coefficient of degree $>0$, then any solution to $f(x) = 0$ is an algebraic number. If $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are also polynomials with integer coefficients, is it possible for the solution of $f(x) +g(\sin x) = 0$ to be any real number? What about $f(x) + g(\sin x) + h(\log x) = 0$?

Comment: What do you mean by the solution to an equation? The polynomial equation $y = 1x$ gets you every real number as a solution.

Comment: Infinitely many. The set $\{\sin(n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is countable. So is $\{\log(n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$, etc etc

Comment: @GFauxPas I am talking about equations in one variable.

Comment: @Ovi $1x = 1x$ has every real number as a solution.

Comment: @GFauxPas I am talking about polynomials with degree > 0

Comment: @Kibble I'll raise that to *uncountably* many, if an "*equation*" is taken to mean something that can be represented with a finite number of characters from a finite alphabet.

Comment: @Kibble Would you mind elaborating a little on that point?

Comment: @hardmath Ok I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: @hardmath Edited.

Comment: @Kibble Okay thanks!

Comment: @dxiv If I understand this article correctly, I think this question can have an even shorter answer. If a number is the root of some equation, then it is a definable number. But most reals are undefinable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number

Comment: @Ovi Not exactly. The equation $0 \cdot x=0$ has every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as a root. The equation $\sin x = 0$ has infinitely many roots. But if you restrict it to equations involving functions with countably many roots then, yes, if follows from countability arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of constructing all the real numbers this way. Even if we have a countable set of special functions $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and only allow arguments from any countable set (integers / rationals / algebraic numbers) then the set of numbers we can construct this way will be countable. The set of real numbers is uncountable so there will be real numbers we cannot get as $f_n(x)$ for $n,x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If I understand this article correctly, I think this question can have an even shorter answer. If a number is the root of some equation, then it is a definable number. But most reals are undefinable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number

Comment: @Ovi That relies on exactly the same property: countability. Also you need to quantity it a bit better for it to be true: "if a number is a root of some equation which has a finite number of terms and whose coefficients are taken from some countable set then ...". It's not true otherwise as $f(x) = x - a$ has $a$ as a root for all real numbers $a$.